# Proof of density of $C_c(E)$ in $L^p(\mu)$ for regular Borel measures on a locally compact space.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

This is a Theorem from Bauer's Measure and Integration Theory.

**29.14 Theorem.** For any regular Borel measure $\mu$ on a locally compact space $E$ and any $p\in [1,\infty)$, the vector space $C_c(E)$ is dense in $\mathcal{L}^p(\mu)$ with respect to convergence in $p$th mean.

[image]

Up to here I understand. However, below, the author states that the matter even comes down to approximating the indicator functions $1_A$ of Borel sets $A$ having $\mu(A)<\infty$. But, for elementary functions, it is possible that the associated indicator functions have infinite measure. So I don't understand why it suffices to only consider those sets with finite measure. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could explain this to me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is simply that such an indicator function would not be in $L^p$.  You only need those in $L^p$ to get elementary functions that are in $L^p$.